# onclick not triggering in Firefox 4.0 but works in Firefox 2.0

Tags: javascript, firefox, triggers, onclick

I have a radio button that triggers in Firefox 2.0 but it does not trigger in Firefox4.0. The radio button html is below and then the javascript that should be triggered. Puzzled as to why it won't work if anyone could help.

```
<td class="Label" colspan="3">
<input class="Label" type="radio" tabindex="3" onclick="document.lending.sec5vallchoice.value=this.value;onGuaranteeChange();" value="3" name="sec5vall">The text beside radio button</td>

// Letter of Guarantee
case SecText5:

        if(sec5val1[rowNumber] == "1") {
            document.lending.sec5val1[0].checked = true;
        }
        else if(sec5val1[rowNumber] == "2") {
            document.lending.sec5val1[1].checked = true;
        }
        else if(sec5val1[rowNumber] == "3") {
            document.lending.sec5val1[2].checked = true;
        }
        else {
            document.lending.sec5val1[3].checked = true;
        }

        document.lending.sec5val1choice.value = sec5val1[rowNumber];
        onGuaranteeChange();

        document.lending.sec5val2.value = sec5val2[rowNumber];
        document.lending.sec5val3.value = sec5val3[rowNumber];

        disableTab(61);
        disableTab(65);
        disableTab(68);
        disableTab(67);
        disableTab(74);
        disableTab(75);
        disableTab(76);
        disableTab(77);
        disableTab(78);
        disableTab(79);
        disableTab(80);
        disableTab(81);
        disableTab(82);
        disableTab(83);
        disableTab(84);
        disableTab(85);
        disableTab(86);
        disableTab(66);
        disableTab(69);
        disableTab(87);

        showPanel(71, 'panel71');
        document.lending.sec5val1[0].focus();
        break;
```

The Function:

```
function onGuaranteeChange() {
if(document.lending.sec5val1choice.value == "3") {
    document.getElementById("loglabel1").innerText = "Enter Life Policy/Mortgage Details";
    document.getElementById("loglabel2").innerText = "";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("loglabel1").innerText = "Amount of Guarantee";
    document.getElementById("loglabel2").innerHTML = "&#163;";
}
```

}

Comment: "Mozilla/5.0" is a user agent part shared by all browsers, which one do you mean? Firefox 4 a year old and has bee out of support for almost just as long, the current Firefox version is Firefox 10 - did you try it?

Comment: sorry I mean Firefox 2.0 instead of Mozilla 5.0. the thing is its an upgrade rollout and the decision has been made on these browsers. So upgrade is from Suse Operating System with Firefox 2.0 to Ubuntu Operating System with Firefox 4.0. the onclick works fine on the old browser but not on the new one. Puzzled

Comment: Your code shows `document.lending` being used excessively but doesn't show where it is defined.

Comment: rowNumber = getRadioValue(document.lending.securradioEdit);

Comment: there seems to be 10,000 document.lending. I don't see that its relevant though to the onclick not functioning. its just retrieving a value

Comment: out of ideas :( . would it be something small not triggering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

innerHTML instead of innerText works! :)